# Function starts duplicate process while initial process still running

Tags: grails, groovy, coldfusion

I have a Grails application that takes input from a .csv and makes a SOAP call for each row to add the data to an external system. The process works fine with a smaller data set, say 200 records. However, with a larger data set, the process will be chugging along with no apparent issue, and then a second "instance" will start and run in parallel to the initial instance. This is causing me to have duplicate entries in the external system. I am not sure exactly what the threshold is where the duplication will occur.

In the past, I had nearly the same problem with a ColdFusion application. That app would take xml input over a web service call, iterate through email recipients in the xml, and send out emails. With 500 recipients in the file, the emails would send out without issue. With 10000 recipients in the file, however, the same "duplication" issue would sometimes occur where the process would be running and the emails sending, and then a second "instance" would start up at the beginning of the list and start sending out duplicate emails.

Since I have observed the problem in the two different environments that both share java at their foundation, I'm thinking the problem is somewhere in the tuning of my java environment. Can someone point me in the right direction as to what I should be looking at in the environment to resolve this issue? Or, if you think the issue is somewhere other than the environment, what else should I be looking at? I know that code only does what you tell it to do, but I am 100% certain that nothing in the code is telling the process to start a second time in mid process. If there is a problem with the code, it must be something like code that is inducing memory leaks or something along those lines.

Comment: My money would be on you having a timer, or some code which is running the process again

Comment: Maybe you should do the process in chunks a 200 records

Comment: Does grails produce any log files you can look at?

Comment: Best to add some sort of flag after each row is "checked out" by the code so it doesn't duplicate process but you obviously have some other issue at the heart of this issue.  This isn't normal behavior or grails or coldFusion.

Comment: We have started processing the requests in smaller batches as a temporary workaround. A longer-term workaround is to flag the records as suggested by BKK, which is how I resolved the issue in the CF app. We would still like to understand what is at the heart of the issue though, so that we can truly correct it. We do have log files, and there have been no clues in the log files so far, meaning no errors. Perhaps our next step needs to be kicking the log files into debug and seeing if there are any clues there.